# Check for dupes before you migrate!

Tags: discussion, migration

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/683797/revisions was just migrated to DIY. It is an exact duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/283251/wiring-from-meter-to-panel-over-longer-distances which the OP cross-posted at the same time and already has an answer. Migrating this dupe is a waste of everybody’s time: the mod here moving it, and us on DIY closing it. Everyone would have been better off just leaving it deleted here.

Comment: Migration is almost always just causing more problems than it solves indeed. Although the person wasting everyone's time in this case is the user who thought that cross-posting on multiple sites at once was a good idea.

Comment: @nobody did you know that there is a review que? Did you know that mods can reject and approve migrations? I would suggest talking to your mods.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because : What nobody said.

Answer (score 2):

I migrated the question.
No act of kindness goes unpunished :-).

I THINK I migrated it before the duplicate was answered, but my antipodean time zone and the lack of detail on the migrate time makes this unclear. (Most actions have a to the minute time-stamp. Migration appears not to have).

That said, I didn't check first, I should have done so.
It didn't occur to me that the user had broken site rules by cross postimg.
Note to self: Be less trusting of people. Ignore people asking good questions in the wrong place; they'l learn.

...

:-) :-(.

FWIW - I have seen quite a few questions over time which have been migrated into and out of SEEE with good results. IMHO. As ever.